# Expected size of set of elements of B not in the image of a function mapping A to B drawn randomly and uniformly from set of all such functions?

Tags: probability

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets such $|A| = m$ and $|B| = n$. Let $Ω$ be the set of all functions from $A$ to $B$. (I.e. $Ω = B^A$.) Let f be function drawn uniformly at random from Ω. Let the random variable X be the cardinality of set of elements of B that are not in the image of f. Formally,
$X=|\{b\in B:(\forall a\in A)(f(a)\not = b)\}|$.

What is the expectation of $X$?

Comment: Have you tried computing $P(X=k)$ for each $k\le n$? Then $\mathbb E X$ is $\sum_{k\le n} k P(X=k)$.

Comment: Those were my initial thoughts, yes, but I'm confused as how to calculate $P(X=k)$. The domain and codomain are of different size and although we are dealing with a uniform distribution of functions, I don't think that translates into uniformity in probability of sizes of $X$.

Comment: If the size is $k$, there $\binom{n}{k}$ ways to choose the range.  Then we have to put $m$ balls in $k$ bins with no empty bins, and each of these ways is considered equally likely.

Answer (score 1):

The mapping of each element of $A$ is independent of the others and is equally likely to result in any element of $B$. Thus the probability that a given element of $B$ is not in the image of $f$ is

$$
\left(1-\frac1n\right)^m\;.
$$

There are $n$ elements in $B$, so by the linearity of expectation the expected number of elements in $B$ that are not in the image of $f$ is

$$
n\left(1-\frac1n\right)^m\;.
$$