# Size of preimage in a pseudo random function

Tags: probability, random-functions

I am interested in statistics of pseudo random functions. In particular, in the following. Given:

- a pseudo random function $f : S \to S$ (with $s = |S|$),
- and a set $D \subseteq S$ (with $n = |D|$) of arbitrary elements,

what is the expected size of the preimage of $D$ through $f$? In other words, $\mathbb{E}[|\{x \in S \mid f(x) \in D\}|]$.

The reverse problem is easier (to me): given the same $f$ and a set $C \subseteq S$ (with $m = |C|$) of arbitrary elements what is the expected size of the image of $C$ through $f$?

We have $\mathbb{E}[f(C)] = s(1-(1-1/s)^m) \approx s(1-\exp(-m/s))$. See e.g. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3622778/expected-size-of-set-of-elements-of-b-not-in-the-image-of-a-function-mapping-a-t) for argument on a very similar development.

Curious if we can use a similar reasoning for the preimage scenario.

---

My attempt so far:

I start by computing the probability that the preimage size is a given size:
\begin{align*}
 \Pr(|C| = m \mid |D| = n) &= \Pr(n \text{ points all map to a different image}) \times \Pr(\text{the other } m-n \text{ points map to an existing image}) \times {m \choose n}\\
   &= \left(\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} 1-\frac i s\right) (n/s)^{m-n} {m \choose n}\\
 \Pr(|C| < n \mid |D| = n) &= 0
\end{align*}

Then compute the weighted average for the expected value:
\begin{align*}
 \mathbb{E}(|C| \mid |D| = n) &= \sum_{m=0}^s m \Pr(|C| = m \mid |D| = n)\\
         &= \sum_{m=n}^s m \left(\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} 1-\frac i s\right) (n/s)^{m-n} {m \choose n}\\
         &= \left(\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} 1-\frac i s\right) \sum_{m=n}^s m (n/s)^{m-n} {m \choose n}
\end{align*}

However the result is unweildy (in particular difficult to compute if $s$ is large), and I am not sure of its correctness.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Shaun Hopefully the question is now up to quality standards.

Comment: What's your definition of a pseudorandom function?

Comment: The same as the one [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_function_family). For the purpose of this development, what I believe matters is that $\Pr(f(x) = y) = \frac 1 s$ for any given $y$. Though maybe other properties are important?